# How to fetch data from two different tables having equal value of sum for same sales id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables:

[image]

`saleid` is the column in common. I can individually obtain the sum of the totals for each table:

```
select saleid, sum(quantity) 
from table1
group by saleid;

select saleid, sum(extracted) 
from table2
group by saleid;
```

I need to compare the sum of extracted, in table 2, with the sum of quantity in table 1 for each sale

What tool of SQL Server or SQL could I use to join the outputs of the sum query and get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query with inner join and subquery:

```
select a.saleid, quantity ,extracted from
(select saleid, sum(quantity) as quantity from table1 group by saleid)a
inner join
(select saleid, sum(extracted) as extracted from table2 group by saleid)b
on a.saleid=b.saleid
group by a.saleid
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `saleid` is same in both the tables, you can join both the tables over the column and get your data via the below query

```
select t1.saleid, 
       sum(t1.quantity) , 
       sum(t2.extracted)
  from table1 t1 join table2 t2 
    on t1.saleid = t2.saleid
group by t1.saleid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select t1.saleid, t1.quantitySum, t2.extractedSum from
(Select saleid, sum(quantity) as quantitySum from table1 group by saleid)t1 
inner join (Select saleid, sum(extracted) as extractedSum from table2 group by saleid)t2 on t1.saleid= t2.saleid and t1.quantitySum=t2.extractedSum ;
```